# Tricky normal distribution problem

Tags: probability

I'm given the following question:
[image]

yet I seem to have the wrong answer.
My working is as follows:

Let $P$ be the piston diameter.
Let $C$ be the cylinder diameter.
Then:
$$P \sim N(10.42,0.0009);$$
$$C \sim N(10.43,0.0016)$$

Hence: $$P-C \sim N(-0.01,0.0025)$$.
$\Pr\{\text{piston does not fit the cylinder}\}=\Pr(P>C)=\Pr(P-C>0)=1-\Pr(P-C<0)=1-\Phi(\frac{0--0.001}{\sqrt{0.0025}})=1-\Phi(0.02)=0.492$ which is not equal to any of these answers.

Comment: You should have 0.2 rather than 0.02 in the second to last expression

Comment: Why? $0.001/\sqrt{0.0025}=0.02$.

Comment: Yes sorry, ignore me, reading too fast

Comment: Is there a reason why $\mu$ is not -0.01 in both places?

Comment: I've written it down in my working: $P-C \sim N(-0.01,0.0025)$ (using the fact that $\mu_{P-C}=\mu_P-\mu_C$ and that $Var[P-C]=Var[P]+Var[C]$)

Comment: Right. But in the z-score calculation you are using -0.001 (with 2 zeros)

Comment: Damn it! Thanks! Is everything else essentially correct apart from this?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: So I was inadvertently right after all!